# Firebase with loading indicator

Tags: firebase

How can I add a loading indication when using this?

```
new Firebase('url/data').on('child_change',function() {
   // do somthing here, which may take x time per operation
})
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get a "the data has changed, the actual changes are on their way" notification with Firebase. It constantly pushes the changes to your client, so the actual updates are often quite small. A notification might well take longer to arrive than the actual data.

Answer (score 7):

How about this: add the loading indicator to the DOM beforehand, then use the `value` event to hide it when the location is finished loading, something like (jQuery for brevity):

```
var $load = $('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>').appendTo('body')
  , db = new Firebase('url/data')

db.on('value', function () {
  $load.hide()
})
```

`value` will fire again when the data changes, so make sure the event is something like "remove this class" rather than "toggle this class".

Read about the different events: [Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html).

Comment: This is actually our recommended approach.

Comment: I think the problem with this approach is that if your query does not yield any results, the callback function will not be called and you will have 'loading' forever

Comment: @AParacha Do you have a way to avoid this issue?